# How are Hosts and Virtual machines connected?

Tags: tcp, virtual-machine, protocols, connect, host

I'm struggling to understand if the reason for a host and virtual machines connection is through the internet, if it communicates with the host as an application would communicate with the PC it is installed on or if it uses a protocol like TCP (As it purpose is to connect 2 devices so they can exchange streams of data, so it would make sense that the VM and Host were connected by this protocol).

All answers are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

As by the definition of virtual machines, they run on a hosts hardware in **virtually separate areas**, so the host and Virtual machines **do not share virtual memory** and both systems can have completely different operating systems.

This means, that those two systems are **completely separate** and can be connected through a variance of interfaces - for example via a network connection (TCP/IP or UDP), if host and vm are connected directly to the network.

See here an article of VMWare about [Host-only-Networking](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html) without the need of the WWW.